# How Do You Apply a Filter Condition to an Array of Strings

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Whenever there is a string in column G that equals any one of the strings in D12:K12 of the sheet titled Instructions I would like to delete that row.

```
function deleteRows() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();

  var host = ss.getRange("Instructions!D12:K12").getValues();
  var rang = sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(), sh.getLastColumn());
  var valus = rang.getValues().filter(r => {if(r[6] != host) return true});
  rang.clearContent();
  sh.getRange(1,1,valus.length,valus[0].length).setValues(valus);
}
```

I believe there is an issue with how I wrote "r[6] != host" related to "host" being an array and not a single string but I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Can anyone offer some advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question of `Whenever there is a string in column G that equals any one of the strings in D12:K12 of the sheet titled Instructions I would like to delete that row.` and your showing script, I believe your goal is as follows.

- About the values of "Instructions!D12:K12", when one of those values is the same as the column "G" in the active sheet, you want to delete rows of the active sheet.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modification points:

- In your script, `host` is a 2-dimensional array. Unfortunately, in this case, `var valus = rang.getValues().filter(r => {if(r[6] != host) return true})` is not correctly worked.
- I thought that `var rang = sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(), sh.getLastColumn());` can be modified to `var rang = sh.getDataRange();`.

#### Modified script:

In this modification, when you activate the sheet and run this script, the search values are retrieved from "Instructions!D12:K12". And, using these values, column "G" of the active sheet is checked. And, the sheet is updated.

```js
function deleteRows() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();

  var host = ss.getRange("Instructions!D12:K12").getValues()[0];
  var rang = sh.getDataRange();
  var valus = rang.getValues().filter(r => !host.includes(r[6]));
  rang.clearContent();
  sh.getRange(1, 1, valus.length, valus[0].length).setValues(valus);
}
```

#### References:

- [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)
- [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: The works perfectly. I've never used includes() before. Thank you.

On this line:
var host = ss.getRange("Instructions!D12:K12").getValues()[0];

Why do you need to put [0]?

Comment: @3jay1 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your additional question of `On this line: var host = ss.getRange("Instructions!D12:K12").getValues()[0]; Why do you need to put [0]?`, `ss.getRange("Instructions!D12:K12").getValues()` returns a 2-dimensional array like `[[1,2,3,,,]]`. `includes` can be used to the 1-dimensional array. So, in order to use this with `includes`, I used `[1,2,3,,,]` by adding `[0]`.

Comment: I am trying to change the host range from D12:K12 to D8:D12. Simply changing those references on the host variable definition line doesn't work. Why is this?

Comment: @3jay1 About your new question of `I am trying to change the host range from D12:K12 to D8:D12. Simply changing those references on the host variable definition line doesn't work. Why is this? `, I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `Simply changing those references on the host variable definition line doesn't work.`. Can I ask you about the detail of your new question? I deeply apologize that I'm trying to correctly understand your new question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem:

```
var valus = rang.getValues().filter(r => {if(r[6] != host) return true});
```

r[6] is a single cell in column 7 but host is a two dimensional array of values.   So that doesn't make any sense.

You could conceivably mean something like this:

```
function deleteRows() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const ish = ss.getSheetByName("Instructions")
  var ivs = ish.getRange("D12:K12").getValues();
  var rg = sh.getRange(1, 1, sh.getLastRow(), sh.getLastColumn());
  var vs = rg.getValues().filter((r, i) => r[6] != ivs[i][6]);
  rg.clearContent();
  sh.getRange(1, 1, vs.length, vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
}
```

Sorry I require making all of my variables as small a possible because I hate to type anymore than I absolutely have to and I like my code to be as small as possible and still work with the editor format

Comment: Thank you! I learned a lot from the last time you replied to my post and I'm sure I will from this time too.

The code fails on this line:  var vs = rg.getValues().filter((r, i) => r[6] != ivs[i][6]);

with TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '6')

Any ideas?